# Removing mark-up from unordered list with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the follow content I need to remove the mark-up tags `<div class="sub">` and `</div`> but not it's content with jquery. This is to adapt the menu to a responsive layout.

```
<nav id="top">  
<ul>
    <li class="ti" id="snw"> <a class="mm" href="/snowdepth/">Weather</a>
       <div class="sub">    

          <ul>
               <li><h2>Snowline</h2></li>
                <li><a href="/alpen/nordliche%20ostalpen/">Nordliche Ostalpen</a></li>    
         </ul>

      </div>
    </li>

    <li class="ti" id="blg"> <a class="mm" href="/live/">Weblog</a></li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: What have you already tried?  We need to see code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/):

```
​$('.sub').find('ul').unwrap()​;
```

Essentially, you are looking for all the child elements of `.sub`, and unwrapping them or removing their parent.

Here's the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yEseX/

Comment: Nice, I'd not come across this function before.

Comment: Love the fiddle url: yEsex? Why indeed??

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PryDD/)**

```
$('.sub').parent().html($('.sub').html());
```

Answer (score 0):

Supposing you may have more than one div with class `sub`, I'd suggest this :

```
var container = $('#top');
container.html(
    container.html().split('<div class="sub">').join('').split('</div>').join('')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 var content = $(".sub").html(); // stored ".sub" div content
 $(".sub").remove(); // remove ".sub" div
 $("#top #snw").after(content); // insert content where you want
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = $('#snw');
var html = list.html();
list.html(html.replace('<div class="sub">','').replace('</div>',''));
```

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/4k59G/)

Answer (score 0):

I think @Abhilash's answer is the neatest so far, but I would modify the selector slightly:

```
$('.sub').contents().unwrap();
```

This removes all of the `.sub` elements, leaving their contents in place.

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/yEseX/2/